# Entity framework core inheritance - foreign key constraint conflict upon insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, inheritance, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework Core and I have the following classes which I'm trying to configure using Fluent API.  EntityType is a discriminator field and EntityReference should be the foreign key for Movie or Book depending on the EntityType.

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKCa.png)

```
public abstract class Review
{
    public Guid ReviewId { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityReference { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Comments{ get; set; }
}

public MovieReview: Review {}

public BookReview: Review {}

public class Movie
{
    public Guid MovieId { get; set; }
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    ...
    ICollection<MovieReview> Reviews {get; set;}
}

public class Book
{
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    ...
    ICollection<BookReview> Reviews {get; set;}
}
```

Configuration classes:

```
public class ReviewConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Review>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Review> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Review");
        builder.HasKey(o => o.ReviewId);
        builder.HasDiscriminator<string>(o => o.EntityType)
            .HasValue<Movie>("Movie")
            .HasValue<Book>("Book");
     }
}

public class MovieConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Movie");
        builder.HasKey(o => o.MovieId);
        ...
        builder.HasMany(o => o.MovieReviews)
            .WithOne(o => o.Movie)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.EntityReference);
    }
}

public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Book");
        builder.HasKey(o => o.BookId);
        ...
        builder.HasMany(o => o.BookReviews)
            .WithOne(o => o.Movie)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.EntityReference);
    }
}
```

When I try to add/update a book review I'm getting the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_Review_Book_EntityReference". The conflict occurred in database, table
> "Book", column 'BookId'.

I can't make any changes to the database tables.  Is there some way to use fluent api configuration to ensure that the EntityReference will link to MovieId when EntityType is 'Movie' and ignore the FK constraint, FK_Review_Book_EntityReference and likewise for Book?

Answer (score 0):

try please change your class definition like this :

```
    public abstract class Review
    {
        public Guid ReviewId { get; set; }
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieReview: Review
    {
        public Guid MovieId { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookReview: Review
    {
        public Guid BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
    }
```

And fluent configuration must be like this :

```
    public class MovieConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Movie");
            builder.HasKey(o => o.MovieId);
            ...
            builder.HasMany(o => o.MovieReviews)
                .WithOne(o => o.Movie)
                .HasForeignKey(v => v.MovieId);
        }
    }

    public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Book");
            builder.HasKey(o => o.BookId);
            ...
            builder.HasMany(o => o.BookReviews)
                .WithOne(o => o.Book)
                .HasForeignKey(v => v.BookId);
        }
    }
```